# Can not see new wireless question after clicking on featured tab

Tags: support

When I click on featured tab it gets stuck and will only show me featured items until I clear all history but after clearing history this time I can not click on wireless tags and see new questions only the old ones can anyone tell me how to be able to see new wireless questions being posted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/wireless?sort=newest